# Postgresql 4 table joins

Tags: postgresql, join

I have one doubt in posgresql joins and filters. Please find below sql code snippets.

1)

```
select count(*)
FROM lfa1 a
LEFT JOIN lfb1 b
    ON a.lifnr = b.lifnr
    and a.hvr_is_deleted = 0
    and b.hvr_is_deleted = 0
    and a.mandt = '100'
    and b.mandt = '100'
LEFT JOIN LFM1 m1
    ON a.lifnr = m1.lifnr
    and m1.mandt = '100'
    and m1.hvr_is_deleted = 0
LEFT JOIN LFM2 m2
    ON a.lifnr = m2.lifnr
    and m1.ekorg= m2.ekorg
    and m2.mandt = '100' 
    and m2.hvr_is_deleted = 0;
```

2)

```
select count(*)
FROM lfa1 a
LEFT JOIN lfb1 b
    ON a.lifnr = b.lifnr

LEFT JOIN LFM1 m1
    ON a.lifnr = m1.lifnr

LEFT JOIN LFM2 m2
    ON a.lifnr = m2.lifnr
    and m1.ekorg= m2.ekorg


WHERE
    a.hvr_is_deleted = 0
    and b.hvr_is_deleted = 0
    and a.mandt = '100'
    and b.mandt = '100'
    and m1.mandt = '100'
    and m1.hvr_is_deleted = 0
    and m2.mandt = '100' 
    and m2.hvr_is_deleted = 0;
```

Both literally having same meaning but logically it's not working as both of the snippets are giving different counts. I want know how controls will be passed here to execute this code.
Can someone help me to understand would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ravi

Comment: These two queries do _not_ have the same meaning, so it follows they return different results.

Comment: The WHERE clauses in the second query turn the outer joins back into inner joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in comments these queries are not equivalent. To understand why the are different, let's examine them:

```
create table A (x int);
insert into A(x) values (1);

create table B (x int, y int);
insert into B(x,y) values (2,2);

select A.x, B.x, B.y
from A
left join B
    on A.x = B.x
    and B.y = 2;
```

Since no rows match the join predicate, B.x and B.y are replaced with null in the resulting relation:

```
A.x B.x     B.y
1   null    null
```

If we move B.y to the where clause:

```
select A.x, B.x, B.y
from A
left join B
    on A.x = B.x
where B.y = 2;
```

you will get 0 rows as a result. To understand why, the WHERE clause is evaluated after the JOIN, so this is the same as:

```
select Ax, Bx, By
from (
    select A.x as Ax, B.x as Bx, B.y as By
    from A
    left join B
        on A.x = B.x
) as T
where By = 2;
```

But

```
    select A.x as Ax, B.x as Bx, B.y as By
    from A
    left join B
        on A.x = B.x
```

still evaluates to

```
Ax  Bx      By
1   null    null
```

so your where clause will be:

```
where null = 2
```

i.e.

```
where null
```

which isn't TRUE, so the result is empty

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6bb7a2c9edc8464222ef25fef8240373)